# Trouble with ~/Applications folder and moving applications on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, applications, folders, root

I recently encountered some issues with the `~/Applications` folder on my macOS system and need some guidance on how to resolve them. Here's what happened:

1. I contacted Apple Support, and a technical advisor informed me that it is not possible to change the default location for saving applications, and they will be stored directly on the disk instead of the `~/Applications` folder. They mentioned that there's no workaround for this. (In retrospect, I think he misunderstood the issue, or did not know the answer and kept repeating what the docs told him.)
2. The `~/Applications` folder keeps reappearing periodically, even after I delete it. Consequently, some of my applications, like Chrome Apps, were mistakenly downloaded to the `~/Applications` folder instead of the designated Applications folder directly on Macintosh HD. This has resulted in a messy situation.

I'm seeking assistance with the following:

1. How can I safely move all my applications from the `Applications` folder to the `~/Applications` folder? I want to ensure that system applications remain intact, and any new user accounts created have access to the standard system applications. In other words, a fresh boot install. When new users are created right now, all my user-installed apps are contained in the new boot.
2. Is there a way to diagnose why this `~/Applications` folder reappears repeatedly and why applications are being saved in the wrong location sometimes? I'm keen to understand the root cause to prevent it from happening again in the future.

Edit: I would like to consolidate the "Applications" folder into a single location, specifically "~/Applications".

In Question 2, it was assumed that all my applications are already in the "Applications" folder on Macintosh HD. However, certain apps like Chrome Apps are installed in the "~/Applications" folder. My assumption is that Chrome searches for the "Applications" folder in the root directory, and if it's not found there, it instructs the Mac to create one in order to download those apps.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to whether you want, or don't want, the `~/Applications` folder. Question 1 seems to be about wanting to move stuff to the user folder; and Q. 2 seems to be about stopping that folder from appearing.

Comment: Sorry, please see the edit for clarification.

Comment: You're still asking about moving applications TO the user folder, but also saying "mistakenly downloaded (?) to ~/Applications". (Surely downloads would go to ~/Downloads, and then be installed by moving to one of the Applications folders.

Comment: Please see the edit now

Comment: Does Chrome use an installer package, or do you just download a disk image and drag the app to the Applications folder?

Comment: Chrome in this case used an installer package, I didn't do drag or manually install any of the Chrome apps, just clicked the install button once on the browser.

Comment: This is still confusing point 2 says "The ~/Applications folder keeps reappearing periodically, even after I delete it." but thenyou ask how to move all apps to the directory you have deleted and want to keep deleted

Comment: My current `Applications` folder is on Macintosh HD. There is no Applications folder now in root, because I've deleted it. In retrospect, the Applications folder gets created by the OS in root folder when it's deleted, even though my applications live in an already existing `Applications` folder on Macintosh HD.

Clearly, applications are meant to live in `~/Applications`. Now, I'd like to know how to safely move the apps from the `Applications` folder on Macintosh HD to `~Applications` folder without causing any issues, if any may be cased by this?

Comment: (The "Applications" folder now exists in the root, but it is empty.) I would like the root "Applications" folder to contain all my current apps, moving them from the "Applications" folder on Macintosh HD without causing any issues.

Comment: It should not be possible to delete /Applications, nor to empty it.

Comment: Yes, I cannot delete the Applications folder on disk, but on root it can deleted, however, when it is deleted in root, it gets created again. I have my user-installed apps in the Applications folder on Macintosh HD and want to safely move them all to Applications on root.

Comment: You're logging in as the root user? Don't do that.

Comment: What do you mean do not login as the root user?

Comment: I mean don't do that. There is no need for it. It is disabled by default. Or do you mean something else by "It is deleted in root".

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding something. I just want to know how if I can safely move my user-installed apps from one Applications folder to another — the user-installed apps from disk directly to root.

https://share.cleanshot.com/cFTd7p84
https://share.cleanshot.com/FzrtRC4b

Comment: That image is of the user Applications folder, and it is empty. All is well. Also, you root level Applications folder has apps in it. This is how things should be.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't my user-installed apps be in the user's folder? When creating a new user, the apps installed on the `kamil` user are also installed, and that's not the right behaviour.

Comment: Normally, apps installed by the user go into /Applications, not ~/Applications.

Comment: I have read the answer you have given, and it answers my question. I simply wanted to know how to safely move user-installed apps from the disk to the user. I have a tendency to make simple things complex. I'm sorry. Thanks for your help, and take care!

Comment: Don't move the apps! Leave them in the root level folder.

Comment: I need to move user-installed apps from the Macintosh HD to root folder, I'm not doing the opposite. When I do that, only an alias is created though...

Comment: What do you mean "from Macintosh HD to root folder"? Macintosh HD is the root.

Comment: Post an image into your question, showing the location of the apps that you want to move.

Comment: Root folder of the user: ~/. Isn't that root? Isn't disk the disk folder?

Comment: Root is `/`,  the top level of the file system. Saying 'root of the user' is confusing.

Comment: Do not move your apps from `/Applications`. Do not put them in the user `~/Applications` folder.

Comment: I'm sorry. So I wanted to move user-installed apps from root `/` to `/~` tile, or user folder for which those user-installed apps apply, but I can only create an alias: https://share.cleanshot.com/XgbbPc3j

Comment: An alias is created when you don't have permission to move the item by dragging.  So it just makes a 'link' to the original. I think I've explained as much as I can. See the added text in bold in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

By default, macOS has an Applications folder at the root level of the file system: `/Applications`. *(see below for more details.)*

This is where all third-party apps normally get installed to. Installing them in this location means that they are separate from any given user account, and they are available to all users.

Due to the 'parallel' structure of macOS, several folders in the root level can have 'counterparts' in the user domain: you can create an `~/Applications` folder, and the OS will use apps installed there; but of course they will only be available to that user account.

Unless your computer is used by several different people, with different user accounts, who must not have access to the same apps, I would recommend keeping your apps in `/Applications`, and not in the user account. It makes finding and fixing problems easier, and also makes backup strategies more flexible.

**In short: Do not move apps from "Macintosh HD > Applications".**

It's possible that an installer might create a user Applications folder, if it is incorrectly programmed, or perhaps if it can't write to `/Applications`, for some reason.

An admin user should be able to move any app from `~/Applications` to `/Applications`. You may be asked for authorisation to do so.

*(Since Big Sur, apps that are part of the OS, like TextEdit, Safari, Mail, etc, are actually at a different location, on a separate system volume, but they are shown as 'merged' with the `/Applications` folder, in the Finder.)*